# Multiple databases in django with migrations

Tags: django, django-migrations

I have two databases configured, one for all but one tables, table, which I have in the second database, database2. I store data, and retrieve data perfectly without using any router, just the 'using' attribute on the save and the get. I was upgrading our app to django 1.8 a while ago, and it seemed to be working, table in database2 doesn't change that often, but it has been working ok since the upgrade.

But now I need to make a change to table in database2.

So I try manage.py migrate table --database database2. The migration seems to take, but I get an error in the end.

RuntimeError: Error creating new content types. Please make sure contenttypes is migrated before trying to migrate apps individually.

I've been trying to add contentypes and auth as fake migrations in database2, but I still get the error. Will adding a router make it go away? Are there any other ways?

Thanks!